# SQL Count from specific Column in Database

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to get a SQL Count of the number of records that pertain to my bundnum column and display it into my textblock. Any suggestions?

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("db connection");

SqlCommand comm = conn.CreateCommand();

comm.CommandText = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM dbo.tablename WHERE bundnum = 'values' ";
conn.Open();
int returnValue = (int)comm.ExecuteScalar();
txtNumber.Text = returnValue.ToString();
```

Comment: Can you share some sample data and the result you're trying to achieve? I'm not sure I'm following...

Comment: What's wrong with what your current code is doing?

Comment: What about SELECT COUNT(bundnum)...?

Comment: I am wanting to count a specific column (bundnum) in my database and retrieve a specific number in that column (which is from a textblock called txtBundle2 that a user enters a number into) and display that specific count into the txtNumber textblock

Answer (score 0):

Using Google, I found this [helpful link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar(v=vs.110).aspx) and after some modification:

```
Int32 newCount = 0;
string newValue = "something";
string sql =
    "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM dbo.tablename WHERE bundnum = '@myValue'";
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString))
{
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@myValue", SqlDbType.VarChar);
    cmd.Parameters["@myValue"].Value = newValue;
    try
    {
        conn.Open();
        newCount = (Int32)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }
}
```